# Keep only fresh 200 records for each group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns like 
id | name | date | group ..

What i want to do is delete all old records for each group with count more than 200.

For example I have a group called "shoes" which has 400 records
"giftcard" has 300 records, "electronics" has 100 records, etc , etc

So after running a SQL query what i want is the count of each group (shoes, giftcard,electronics, etc) be less than or equal to 200.
The records to delete are the old records identified either by date or by id (auto increment).
So 200 records from "shoes" group will be deleted which were older than the ones kept or had id less than the ones kept.

Comment: get the highest id, subtract 200 from it and delete all the records below that id.

Comment: @Maximin, you're assuming id's are consecutive.

Answer (score 3):

This type of problem is a little bit inconvenient in MySQL, because they have not implemented SQL-99 windowing functions like ROW_NUMBER(). MySQL does not support this feature until version 8.0.

Here's a solution that works on MySQL 5.7 and earlier in a single SQL statement, and can select only for the members of each group greater than the 200th. It uses a MySQL feature called [user variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html), which keep their value as your query processes from row to row.

```
DELETE f FROM foo AS f
JOIN (SELECT id, IF(@g = `group`, @rn:=@rn+1, @rn:=1) AS row_number, @g:=grp
        FROM foo, (SELECT @g:=null, @rn:=0) _init
        ORDER BY `group`, date desc) AS r
ON f.id = r.id AND r.row_number > 200;
```

Before you run this (or anything that deletes data!), I recommend you understand how it works, and test it with an equivalent SELECT to make sure it is selecting the rows you want to delete.

I tested this with a smaller data set. Here's the data when I ran it with no filtering:

```
SELECT f.id, f.`group`, r.row_number FROM foo AS f
JOIN (SELECT id, IF(@g = `group`, @rn:=@rn+1, @rn:=1) AS row_number, @g:=grp
        FROM foo, (SELECT @g:=null, @rn:=0) _init
        ORDER BY `group`, date desc) AS r
ON f.id = r.id;

+----+--------+------------+
| id | group  | row_number |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 |      1 |          1 |
|  2 |      1 |          2 |
|  3 |      1 |          3 |
|  5 |      1 |          4 |
| 11 |      1 |          5 |
|  4 |      2 |          1 |
| 10 |      2 |          2 |
|  8 |      2 |          3 |
|  7 |      3 |          1 |
|  6 |      3 |          2 |
| 12 |      3 |          3 |
|  9 |      4 |          1 |
+----+--------+------------+
```

And here's the SELECT that skips the first 2 per group:

```
SELECT f.id, f.`group`, r.row_number FROM foo AS f
JOIN (SELECT id, IF(@g = `group`, @rn:=@rn+1, @rn:=1) AS row_number, @g:=grp
        FROM foo, (SELECT @g:=null, @rn:=0) _init
        ORDER BY `group`, date desc) AS r
ON f.id = r.id AND r.row_number > 2;

+----+-------+------------+
| id | group | row_number |
+----+-------+------------+
|  3 |     1 |          3 |
|  5 |     1 |          4 |
| 11 |     1 |          5 |
|  8 |     2 |          3 |
| 12 |     3 |          3 |
+----+-------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. To people that are newbies like me: The last word `grp` in the second line should be changed to `group` too.

Answer (score 1):

Run this psuedo-SQL

```
SELECT shoes.id FROM shoes ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 200
```

Then parse the results from that (an array.. (1, 2, etc) -- call this $IDS )

```
DELETE FROM shoes WHERE ID NOT IN ($IDS)
```

EDIT: To do it all as a SQL query, there are two possible ways.

**1**. `DELETE FROM shoes WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT shoes.id FROM shoes ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 200)` -- yes, you can do this. Be careful. As Bill suggests, First run this first as a `SELECT * FROM shoes WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT shoes.id FROM shoes ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 200)` to make sure it is selecting the correct things [That you want to DELETE!]

**2**. Don't know that much about DECLARE, but you might be able to declare `@IDs =  SELECT shoes.id FROM shoes ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 200`, then `DELETE FROM shoes WHERE ID NOT IN (@IDS)`

Both are untested. By the way, you should use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to set up mock schema information so that when people come to help they can test their queries.

Comment: how would you suggest to do this entirely in SQL query

Comment: The OP wanted to keep the first 200 *per group*, not the first 200 in the whole table. Also, MySQL user-defined variables cannot hold a whole data set, they can only hold a single scalar value. Nor can you use a variable as the code for a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

This would be an SQL Server Solution

```
Select * from (
Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By [Group] order by Date) RN  
from table) t1
inner join (
Select [GROUP], COUNT(*) as Cnt
from table
group by [Group]
) a on a.[Group] = t1.[Group]
where t1.RN <= 200
and a.Cnt >= 200
```

Edit:

Here's using a CTE

```
With CTE as 
(
    Select [GROUP], COUNT(*) as cnt
    from tbl
    group by [Group]
)

Select t1.* 
from (Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By [Group] order by Date) RN  
      from tbl) t1
inner join CTE a on a.[Group] = t1.[Group]
where t1.RN <= 200 and 
      a.Cnt >= 200
```

Comment: Nice, correct solution for Microsoft SQL Server, but unfortunately MySQL does not support windowing functions or CTE's yet.

Comment: The query gives an error. near the opening round brace of partition

Comment: @dipamchange, as Bill said this is an MS SQL Server solution, I blacked out that you were using MySQL. Maybe there's a way to translate this into MySQL

Comment: Ohh k , actually I am not aware how we could translate this to MySQL supported query, anybody here have any pointers on it?

Comment: Instead of using a CTE you could use a temp table. There has to be a `Row_Number` type of function in MySQL

Comment: @CSharper, no, there is not. Windowing functions have been requested since 2008, but not implemented. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35893

Comment: @Bill, how would you suggest mimicking that functionality for the task at hand?

Comment: @CSharper, I posted a solution as an answer.